# Database retreival in android

Tags: android, database

I am retrieving data from database using select query.My requirement is i have to sum the (total) column where `group=household` and `category=Income`.I have 1 entry in database which satisfy this condition.But it returns always 0.Please help me.

My query is:

```
long sum=0;
    Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(
             "SELECT SUM("+(KEY_TOTAL)+") FROM incomexpense WHERE groups='Household' & category='Income'",null);
     if(cursor1.moveToFirst())
     {
       sum = cursor1.getLong(0);
     }
     cursor1.close();
     String housetotal=String.valueOf((long)sum);       
     System.out.println("house="+housetotal);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the `&` with `AND` in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the query might not have worked because you have written '&' instead of 'and'